# Detect files changes in python

Tags: python

I wanted to detect changes in certain directories, and if I heard changes in the files, for example, many changes at the same time it would return some print and perform certain actions. (I'm programming for linux)

```py
import sys
import time
import logging
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import LoggingEventHandler



if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Set the format for logging info

    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                        format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')


    # Set format for displaying path

    #path = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else '.'
    path = '/home/kali/Downloads'
    event_handler = LoggingEventHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
```

I'm using this base code to perform the actions, but how can I put the conditions of several changes using this base?

Comment: So what is the problem? What do you expect the code to do?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: You can't detect "several changes".  All you can know is whether the file has changed since the last time you checked.  Did it change once?  Did it change 9 times?  There's no way to know.